# Is it possible to connect more than 4 Wireless Xbox 360 controllers to a PC?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, controllers

If I buy multiple [Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receivers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2) will I be able to use them at the same time? I know that each one should support 4 controllers, so if I buy 2 could I connect 8?

Comment: I'm sure they exist, but I can't think of a game that supports more than 4 controllers.

Comment: @Twon-ha a super-splitscreen multiplayer game or with a lot of characters on the main screen. A game like Realm of the Mad God, but for local multiplayer. Inventory management could be a hell, though.

Comment: Gang beasts and Knight squad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can use more than 4 wireless controllers on some games. For example Gang Beasts, Knight Squad, Miner Warfare and Screencheat support up to 8 controllers via DirectInput instead of XInput.

> XInput supports a maximum of four controllers at a time. This is an Xbox limit, carried over to Windows. Although as of 2010 few PC games require more than four controllers at once, DirectInput itself has no such limitation.
>
> ([Wikipedia, DirectInput vs. XInput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput#DirectInput_vs_XInput))

DirectInput works with any controller including Xbox controllers. The use of DirectInput or Xinput is down to the developer or engine that they are using. It is not something that you can configure in Windows.

Update:
I noticed that the upcoming [windows wireless adapter](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/controllers/windows-10-wireless-adapter/) states that it "(s)upports up to 8 wireless controllers". I wonder if they've removed the XInput limit and whether this will be for windows 10 only or if they will eventually backport to Windows 7.

Comment: it does say in its specifications "for use with Windows 10". Add to it the fact that Windows 10 has had a massive gaming revamp, including xbox integration. This would most definitely, at the very least, cause issues on a non-windows 10 computer. Also, your own references seem to validate the other answer, but not your own. *As of 2011 XInput is for Xbox 360 controllers, while DirectInput is for any controller. * where OP is specifically asking about the 360 controller. Can you tell the computer to use directinput for the 360 controller? If so, how?

Comment: Any controller includes Xbox 360 controllers. It's up to the game developer or engine they use whether they support xinput or directInput. No configuration is required from the user. Knight squad and Gang beasts both use directInput and I've played both with 8 Xbox 360 controllers, so we can put that to bed. I'm hoping MS will see sense and backport the new adapter drivers to Windows 7 - how hard could it be?

Answer (score 7):

You can connect them, and all the controllers will show up as devices on your PC, but you won't actually be able to use more than 4 controllers.

XInput (the API that Windows games use to interface with Xbox 360 controllers) [only supports a maximum of 4 controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#multiple_controllers). Even if there were a way around this, games are designed with this limitation in mind.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect as some games use directInput which supports more than 4 controllers, see other answer.

Comment: The vast majority of games support Xbox 360 controllers by way of XInput, which has this hard limit, so this doesn't seem particularly relevant.

Comment: The vast majority of games aren't suitable for 8 local players either. How are recent 8 player games not relevant?

Answer (score 2):

I just got 7 xbox controllers to work perfectly on Win 10. The setup was crazy: 2 dongles plugged to the PC, three wireless controllers, two cabled controllers plugged to the PC and other two other cabled ones plugged to another PC (for lack of USB slots on this one), but all of them working on this PC.